# Laravel naming 'Where' and AJAX statements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

This is something I could not find documentation for. I need to have multiple AJAX searches for my page. They all come from the same database. The only difference about the searches is that they might need to only take and search only one  column.

For example: My page consists of an input that searches that whole database, a select that allows my to filter by country and another filter that allows me to filter by type.

The problem that I am having is that I am unable to, for example make the select only search the `country` column. It searches the whole database, while I need it to search only one column.

The problem comes in that I am using one controller for everything - which works when you only need to search the whole database. When it comes to only searching a specified column, it does not work. This is the controller in question:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('country','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('object_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
        })
->where('site', $site_code)->get();
```

This controller allows to search my database with ease. I will now show my AJAX request:

```
$("#filter-country").change(function() {
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
        data: {'search':$value, type:'country'},
        success: function(data){
          $('#launchsatdisplay').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This gets the search request that the user gave. This, again works perfectly and manages to get the results I want. The only thing is that it searches my whole database, while I only want to search the `country` column in my database.

Basically, my question is: Would I be able to name the AJAX request, for example `country` and ask my controller to only use the `->orWhere('country')` search request, so it only uses the `country` column in my database? Is is possible to name them somehow?

Comment: You mean `->orWhere($request->type, 'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%'):`?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - Unfortunately that does not work. Whenever I search I get a 500 server error. I guess this is because it adds a `&type=country` to the search URL.

Comment: That means you have to be sure that the text in 'type' is equivalent to a column on your database table

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi I can confirm that the text is equivalent to a column.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - I managed to fix it! The only thing is that it still searches the whole database and not the column. We need something that only asks the AJAX to use the `where` statement with the `type`.

Comment: how about removing other 'orWheres()` that you don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `type` to specify the type of search, you can use that within your subquery:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
        if(empty($request->type) && empty($request->rocket_type)) {
            $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('country','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('object_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
        } else {
            if(!empty($request->type)) { // If the type is specified, use it
                $q->orWhere($request->type,'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');

            }
            if(!empty($request->rocket_type)) { // If the rocket_type is specified, use it
                $q->orWhere('rocket_type','LIKE','%'.$request->rocket_type.'%');

            }
        }

    })
    ->where('site', $site_code)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! - Works perfectly! One thing - what is process if I want to add another search, say for example that only filters the column `rocket_type`. Would I just add another `orWhere` query or would I do something else?

Comment: You'd only need to add it to the else for your whole database search. The `if` block will take care of whatever you pass in as the type.

Comment: I just tried adding `->orWhere($request->rocket_type,'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');` into the `else` statement, but that did not yield any results. I replaced `rocket_type` with `type`. Can you confirm if I am doing this correctly?

Comment: No, if you're passing `rocket_type` as the search type/column, leave the `request->type` alone. No changes are needed there. You only need to add `->orWhere('rocket_type','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')` into the `else` block.

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. It still works for the `country` as in my original question though.

Comment: Try logging your request `Log::info($request->all());` to see what's being passed in. If it's only working for country, then that's what's being passed in. If you want to search for `rocket_type` as well as what you're passing in for the type, then yes, you want to add that as another `orWhere` in the if block.

Comment: Log did not yield any results, just to keep this simple - Is there any chance you can update your answer to add the `rocket_type` AJAX call? Just want to make sure I am not do something wrong. :)

Comment: Sure. Do you want it to always search for `rocket_type`, or only if it's searching the whole database and if the column is specified?

Comment: To keep this simple - I want one input to search for `rocket_type`, another input to search for `country` (already working in your answer). Those should be searching their respective columns and not the whole database. Lastly one input to search the whole database (that should also be working).

Comment: I've updated the code. You may need to tweak whatever you're passing through for the `rocket_type`, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now!

Comment: One more thing - Are you able to allow two filters to work at the same time. If I have two searches and select one, it resets the other one. Is there are chance to stop that? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. It just depends on how you pass the filters into the query. You can add as many `if` filters into that else section as you need. Just don't use `if else`, as that is more like an "if or" instead of "if, then if"